# ActiveRecord Couldn't find Travel with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I search a solution on stackoverflow but there are different issues each time, so I decided to ask the question.
On my application, I have Travel, which has many posts. One user can create many travels, with many posts on one travel. 
But when I try to create a post, I have this error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#create
Couldn't find Travel with 'id'=
```

I don't understand why, so if someone could help me ..
Here is my Posts_controller.rb (create action):

```
def create
    @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
    @post = @travel.posts.new(posts_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Your post is published"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Here is my the models :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :travel

  geocoded_by :country
  after_validation :geocode
end

class Travel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My routes :

```
# Travel
    resources :travels, :shallow => true do
        # Posts
        resources :posts
    end
```

And a ligne for form :

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, :url => travel_posts_path(@travel)) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.text_field :travel_id, placeholder: @travel.id %>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why are you allowing the user to handle `id`s? This is a bad practice.

Comment: I would suggest debugging `params`. You might need to do something like `params[:travel_id]` instead. But I still would not allow users to choose `id`s.

Comment: @Dbz I just try to add the travel id in the :travel_id column of my table post, the field in the form is just here to help me, I'll remove that line when it will work

Comment: My guess is that `id` is returning the `post_id`, and not the `travel_id`, so when you use it to search for the `travel`, it doesn't find it because it is a larger number than all of the travels.

Comment: @Dbz And you're right, when I put :travel_id instead of :id, it work ! thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:id]` will give you the `post`'s `id`, and you're using it to find a `travel`. This could potentially not error and give you the wrong travel, but that's not what you're looking for. You specified `travel_id` in your form, so what you are looking for is `params[:travel_id]`.

In the future you may want to use the `debugger` right at the top of the controller function and `puts` the `params` object to see what's inside. This will give you insight to if you're calling the wrong `key`s and what the structure looks like as things get complicated.